# Get Values in TextBox inside ListView

Tags: wpf

I am created a ListView with TextBox Control.I need to get values in TextBox.

After user typed on Textbox.I need to get whats the user typed.

```
<Window x:Class="LdiaryEditableListView.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Ldiary Editable ListView Sample" Height="350" Width="300">
<StackPanel >
    <ListView Name="listView">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <EventSetter Event="Button.Click" Handler="Button_Click"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" Value="">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
                                        <TextBox  Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=LastName}"/>
                                        <Button Width="70" >Add</Button>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100"  Header="First Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstName}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Last Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastName}"></GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

Iam created a function to get each element in textbox in listview.But it dows not work

```
        foreach(DataRowView itm in lstvQualification.Items)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(itm[0].ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Get the value of the `education` property of your view model. If you need the value immediately when the user is typing, you should set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the Binding.

Comment: Not immediatly...After clicking a button

Comment: Then where is your problem?

Comment: I want to save these text into database when clicking save button

Comment: Add a command to your view model that saves the value of the `education` property. Bind the Button's `Command` property to your view model command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for above my problem.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace LdiaryEditableListView
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<Person> people;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        people = new ObservableCollection<Person>(){
            new Person{FirstName="", LastName=""},
            new Person{FirstName = "Ldiary", LastName="Translations"},
            new Person{FirstName = "English", LastName="Japanese"}
        };
        listView.ItemsSource = people;
    }

    public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _firstName;
        public string FirstName 
        {
            get
            {
                return _firstName;
            }
            set
            {
                _firstName = value;
            }
        }

        private string _lastname;
        public string LastName
        {
            get
            {
                return _lastname;
            }
            set
            {
                _lastname = value;
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Person newPerson = people[0];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newPerson.FirstName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(newPerson.LastName))
        {
            newPerson.FirstName = "";
            newPerson.LastName = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Please provide both first name and last name!");
        }
        else
        {
            Person emptyPerson = new Person()
            {
                FirstName = "",
                LastName = ""
            };
            people.Insert(0, emptyPerson);
        }
        listView.ItemsSource = null;
        listView.ItemsSource = people;
    }
}
```

}